# Why does the Promise execute the 'then' clause before promise has completed?

Tags: javascript, promise

In the following code, the 'then' clause is executed straight away, it doesn't wait for the Promise to complete:

```
function doSomething() { ... }
p = new Promise( ... );
p.then(doSomething()}
```

Whereas this works fine:

```
function doSomething() { ... }
p = new Promise( ... );
p.then(() => {doSomething()}}
```

Please can somebody explain why the two versions aren't equivalent?

Here's some running code to demonstrate it: https://jsfiddle.net/damianhelme/8b6pq9mL/18/

Comment: `then` wants a function **reference** not a an invoked function (unless the invoked function returns a function reference).

Comment: thanks. Curious to hear from people when they down voted the question. I can see now that it was a stupid mistake, but I'm guessing I'm not the first or last to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking `doSomething` and passing its result to `.then`. `() => {...}` creates a new function that will be called by the promise chain. You could also do `.then(doSomething)`, notice no parens.

Comment: doh! thanks - schoolboy error! where's the emoji for 'hanging your head in shame' ...

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are executing the function.

Try this:
p.then(doSomething)
This way you pass a function which will be executed after promise is resolved.

Note there isn't brackets

Comment: thanks, I gave the 'right answer gong' to Daniel on account of him writing first.

Comment: Yep, no problem